# Is there a way to make fragment cache dependency on object stored in session?

Tags: asp.net, caching, outputcache

I have a user control and I want to cache it using:

```
<%@ OutputCache Duration="10" VaryByParam="none" %>
```

Now for dependency I want this cache to depend on object variable I'm storing it in session.
I want this user control cache to be cleared whenever this object value changed.

Thanks

Comment: Your question is too vague. Can you specify!?

Comment: edited my question, please review.

Comment: you might want to provide more information on the context of your scenario.